# Google iOS Cluster Manager "marker.userData" NIL after Cluster/de-Cluster

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am attempting to upgrade my iOS App to use Google Map Clustering.
The App loads over 19,000 markers from a Firebase database using “child added” and I assign an ID to each marker using “marker.userData” as shown below:

```
        dbRef = Database.database().reference()
        let markerRef = dbRef.child("markers")
        //Load all Markers when app starts
        //child added returns all markers, then Listens for new additions
        markerRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { [self] snapshot in
            markerCount = markerCount+1
            let markerKey = snapshot.key
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let x = value?["x"] as? Double
            let y = value?["y"] as? Double
            let v = value?["v"] as? Bool
            
            if v == true {
                //print("adding Verifed icon")
                let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: y ?? 0.0 , longitude: x ?? 0.0)
                let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "VerifiedPin")
                marker.userData = markerKey
                self.markerArray.append(marker)
                //print("marker Array: ", self.markerArray)
                clusterManager.add(marker)
            }else{
                //print("adding Unverifed icon")
                let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: y ?? 0.0 , longitude: x ?? 0.0)
                let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "UnverifiedPin")
                marker.userData = markerKey
                self.markerArray.append(marker)
                //print("marker Array: ", self.markerArray)
                clusterManager.add(marker)
            }
            if(markerCount >= numMarkers {
                self.clusterManager.cluster()
            })
        }) { (error:Error) in
            print("startObservingDB error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            self.noDatabaseConnection()
        }
```

When a user taps on a marker icon “GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker” is called and if “marker.userData” is not GMUCluster, “marker.userData” should contain the ID assigned when the marker was added to the cluster.  This works properly when clustering is not used.

```
    // MARK: - GMSMapViewDelegate
    //Detect when user taps on a specific icon and display the infoBox
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        if marker.userData is GMUCluster {
            // center the map on tapped marker
            viewMap.animate(toLocation: marker.position)
            // zoom in on tapped cluster
            viewMap.animate(toZoom: viewMap.camera.zoom + 1)
            print("Did tap cluster")
            return true
        }
        tappedMarker = marker
        let markerKey = marker.userData as! String
        print("Did tap marker w/key: ", markerKey)

        self.dbRef = Database.database().reference()
        self.dbRef.child(markerKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            let areaObj = Area(snapshot: snapshot)
            let table = areaObj
            print("Table info: ", table)
            self.tableMarker = markerKey
            print("this is table \(markerKey)")
            self.currentTable = table
            print (table.verified)
            self.lblVerified.isHidden = !table.verified
            
            table.itemRef?.child("verified").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let bVerified = snapshot.value as? Bool {
                    table.verified = bVerified
                    self.lblVerified.isHidden = !table.verified
                }
            })
            print("source = \(String(describing: table.source))")
            print("imported = \(String(describing: table.imported))")
            if (table.source != nil) {
                self.btnVerify.isHidden = true
            } else {
                self.btnVerify.isHidden = table.verified
            }
            self.viewPicDetail.isHidden = false
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            if table.lastUpdated == 0.0 {
                let defaultDate = "06/30/2018"
                formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
                let date = formatter.date(from: defaultDate)
                formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.preferredLanguages.first!)
                formatter.dateStyle = .short
                self.lblLastUpdate.text = self.lastUpdateText+"\(formatter.string(from: date!))"
            } else {
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: table.lastUpdated)
                formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.preferredLanguages.first!)
                formatter.dateStyle = .short
                self.lblLastUpdate.text = self.lastUpdateText+"\(formatter.string(from: date))"
            }
            self.refreshDescription()
            self.observeCommentsRatings()
        })
        return false
    }
```

When the map is first displayed, tapping a marker works properly and the “marker.userData” contains the proper ID.  When the map is zoomed-out the markers are clustered and a subsequent zoom-in displays the individual markers.  Tapping on a marker after this operation results in a *Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional* meaning that the value of “marker.userData” is “nil”.

It appears that the cluster manager is corrupting “marker.userData” after clustering the markers then “unclustering” them.

Has anyone else seen this issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The workaround mentioned here has fixed the issue: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/349

Answer (score 0):

I reported this on the GitHub library issue tracker.  The Google development team reproduced the issue, fixed *GMUDefaultClusterRenderer.m* and released version 3.4.2 of the *google-maps-ios-utils* library. More information can be found at:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/349

A big Thanks to the development team for solving this and getting an updated version of the library released quickly.